# Why does my pagination stop working when there is a pop up?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am new to selenium and have written a web scraper but it seems to stop working between pages 5-10, I notice that it stops working when a pop up comes up. is there a way to get around this?

Link: https://www.homedepot.com/b/Milwaukee/Special-Values/N-5yc1vZ7Zzv

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import pandas as pd

website = 'https://www.homedepot.com/b/Milwaukee/Special-Values/N-5yc1vZ7Zzv'
path = '/Users/Office/Documents/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(website)

prod_num = []
prod_price = []

while True:
    try:
        skus = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-identifier--bd1f5')))
        prices = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'price-format__main-price')))
        for sku in skus:
            prod_num.append(sku.text)

        for price in prices:
            prod_price.append(price.text)

        next_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@aria-label="Next"]')))
        time.sleep(3)
        next_page.click()
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        continue

driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame({'code': prod_num, 'price': prod_price})
df.to_csv('HD_test.csv', index=False)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the By.CssSelector("*"), and write the code in a manner of whenever the popup appears it closes the popup and continues the remaining your expected execution.

webElement allElementsFromPage=driver.findelement(By.cssSelector("*");
for(int i=0: i<allElementsFromPage.size();i++)
{
String all=allElementsFromPage.get(i).getText();
if(all.contains("Specify here uniqueness element from the popup")
{
//click on popup to cancel
}
else
{
//click on the pagination element
}
```